# How can i make whole screen semi-black on sidebar open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I have build sidebar with `css` and `jquery`. It's working fine but i want that when sidebar opens then whole screen except sidebar should get semi-black or disabled.

Here is my working 
    [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/8824/)

How can i make whole screen semi-black or disabled on sidebar open?

Comment: ok let me edit the post

Comment: @cale_b here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/8821/

But on fiddle my jquery is not working. On my code editor it is working

Comment: @cale_b i have updated my post please check. Now my fiddle is working fine. Now tell me please that how can i make whole screen semi-black except sidebar?

Comment: Thank You so much. I will surely cleanup my fiddle. Can you please fix guide me one more thing? I have hamburger icon inside my sidebar. But it's not appearing. I don't know why. And also please mention your modified fiddle in your answer so that i can accept

Comment: @cale_b i fixed it. Thanx. Can you put your correct fiddle in answer so i can accept your answer an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general concept to achieve this is fairly straightforward:

1. Modify the javascript to add a class to the `body` when the nav is open (I called it `nav-open`.)
2. Modify the CSS so that the "overlay" element (you already had one in place) is displayed when the body has the class `nav-open`
3. Adjust your overlay element CSS to cause it to show properly (for some reason, it had `opacity: 0` on it, which meant it was *there*, but was not *visible*).

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#sidenav-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  // removed opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 997;
  // set display to none by default
  display: none;
}

// when the body has the class nav-open, display the overlay
.nav-open #sidenav-overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the relevant changes to your javascript:

```
// no-conflict-safe document ready function
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#show-hide-menu').click(function() {
       if ($('#slide-out').hasClass('visible')) {
         // $('#slide-out').removeClass('visible');
         $('#slide-out').toggleClass('close');
       } else {
         $('#slide-out').addClass('visible');
       }

        // check if the nav is "open"
        var open = !$('#slide-out').hasClass('close');

         // for simplicity, always first remove the nav-open from the body
         $('body').removeClass('nav-open');
         // if the nav is open, add the 'nav-open' class to the body
         if (open) {
           $('body').addClass('nav-open');
         }
     });

     // modify to use "on", is best-practice
     // $(document).click(function(e) {
     $(document).on('click', function(e) {
       var sidebar = $(".sidenav, #show-hide-menu");
       if (!sidebar.is(e.target) && sidebar.has(e.target).length === 0) {
         $('#slide-out').toggleClass('close');
         // be sure the nav-open class is removed when the sidebar is dismissed
         $('body').removeClass('nav-open');
       }
     });
});
```

Here is a link to your fiddle, modified with these changes to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/hThGb/8849/

Answer (score 4):

You can use a box-shadow on the sidebar:

```
#sidebar{
 box-shadow:0 0 0 10000px rgba(0,0,0,.50);
}
```

This is black, at .50 opacity. It's set to 10000px to cover the full screen.

Or change rgba(0,0,0,.50) to a solid color like #5a5a5a.

In your case add to your css:

```
#slide-out.visible:not(.close){
  box-shadow:0 0 0 10000px #666666;
}
```

Comment: Bro i want whole screen semi-black except sidebar when sidebar opens.

Comment: can you apply it on my workin fiddle that i mentioned in my post?

Comment: bro, your fiddle doesn't work. This is semiblack. Did you even try it? You can change rgba(0,0,0,.50) to any color like #5a5a5a

Comment: did you try it on my fiddle link?

Comment: Honestly, just copy and paste.

Comment: I fixed it. Can you solve another bug? There is hamburger icon on my sidebar on top right. You can see in my jsfiddle code. But it's not appearing.

Comment: Accept the answer and upvote. And i'll check it out.

Comment: Greatttt!... Helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a content div below your nav. Something like:

   `<div id="maincontent" class="">`
   `<p>Lorem.</p>`
   `</div>`
2. Add some styling so it has min-height, etc.

   `#maincontent {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     min-height: 400px;
   }`
3. Add some JS so when the nav menu button is clicked, it toggles on and off a new style class for this area.

   $('#show-hide-menu').click(function () {

   if ($("div#maincontent").hasClass("overlayed")) {
       $("div#maincontent").removeClass("overlayed");
     }
     else {
       $("div#maincontent").addClass("overlayed");
     }
   });
4. Define the overlayed class in the CSS.

   `.overlayed {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
   }`

Comment: I want this sidebar effect like this website has. https://swopstakes.com/?landingRedirect=true

In this website when sidebar opens then navbar also get beneath that black background.

Comment: Please apply it on my jsfiddle. your solution is not working

Comment: I have applied your code. It's working but navbar still have z-index greater than black background that's why navbar is appearing above black background when sidebar opens